# Hyperlinks getting overlapped with div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: overlapped hyperlink]

I am trying to build a blog-type website where I am fetching the data from the database, everything seems to work correctly but when I am fetching the content
the problem begins whenever the upper div encounters a link the div below gets disturbed. Same as the image shown below. the link in the blue also gets clickable in the div below just
Please point out anything that is wrong in the code. and please suggest any other method if it can be achieved.
Here is the rendered HTML on this site I have hosted it: http://www.beyondtest.tk/

here is the  code that I am using

```
enter code here


 $resultq = mysqli_query($conn,$result2);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultq)) {
                // upto here
                echo '
                <div class="row reviewbox ">
                  <div class="col-md-4 ">
                    <img src="/../admin/'.$row["2"].'" class="revimg img-fluid"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8" >
                    <div>
                      <a class ="title" href ="article.php?article_id='.base64_encode($row['0']).'"> ' .($row['1']) . ' </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="author">
                      <small><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp '.($row[5]).'</i> &nbsp by </small>&nbsp
                      <small><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>&nbsp '.($row[4]).'</small> </br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content">
                        '.truncate($row[3], 200).'
                    </div>

                  </div>
                   <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>';
                }
```

The CSS :

```
    .reviewbox{
  margin: 15px; 
  background-color: white;


}

.revimg{
width: 384.6px;
height:200.8px;
z-index: 2;
margin-left:0;
overflow: hidden;}


small{
  color:#778899;
}

.title,.title a:link{
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#373434;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.author{
  margin-top:5px;
}

.content{
  margin-top:5px;

}
```

Comment: could you post the resulted html, and not the php one, to have a better idea of the result ?

Comment: @jimmyLi added the image tell me if anything more i can add to identify the problem

Comment: @Ashish an image is not the same thing as the rendered HTML. We cannot see if classes etc. are where they should be.

Comment: The best thing you can do is create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will get more help if others **do not have to** 1) guess what might be going on because there's no working example (or missing information) and/or 2) assemble all the code fragments themself.

Comment: @hungerstar you can have a look here http://www.beyondtest.tk/ I hosted it here hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I guess i found the problem. I´m editing my answer. Try not to wrap the col-md-4 with the link. I mean instead of doing this:

```
<div class="row reviewbox ">
    <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/oct/29/uk-digital-services-tax-budget-facebook-google-amazon">
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <img src="/../admin/uploads/images.jpg" class="revimg img-fluid">
        </div>
    </a>
   (...)
```

Try to do this:

```
<div class="row reviewbox ">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/oct/29/uk-digital-services-tax-budget-facebook-google-amazon">
            <img src="/../admin/uploads/images.jpg" class="revimg img-fluid">
        </a>
    </div>
```

The full code should look something like this (please note that i commented 2 empty links):

```
<div class="row reviewbox ">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/oct/29/uk-digital-services-tax-budget-facebook-google-amazon">
            <img src="/../admin/uploads/images.jpg" class="revimg img-fluid">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <!-- <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/oct/29/uk-digital-services-tax-budget-facebook-google-amazon"></a> -->
        <div>
            <!-- <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/oct/29/uk-digital-services-tax-budget-facebook-google-amazon"></a> -->
            <a class="title" href="article.php?article_id=Mg=="> The Guardian view on Donald Trump: using hate as b</a>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            <small><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp; 16:20:38</i> &nbsp; by </small>&nbsp;
            <small><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>&nbsp; Ashish</small> <br>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>It is in keeping with Theresa May’s style of government that a confidence vote on her leadership was
                provoked not by something she did but by something she did not do. Dither has been her...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. I can confirm, i did a test and it works. Don´t wrap the col-md-4 with a link. Do it inside col-md-4, just wrap the image with the desired link.

[image]

Comment: sure gonna try this , can you  please tell me what the html output of my code means ? actually im new to web development does the image do not refer to the same

Comment: Your php output. :)

Comment: i have added an image isnt it visible ? thats the actual problem of overlapping

Comment: White space around the attribute and it's value will not matter, http://jsfiddle.net/5gjvL4qu/1/.

Comment: @NunoBentes you can have a look here http://www.beyondtest.tk/ I hosted it here hope it helps.

Comment: @Ashish Please have a look on my answer, please. :)

Comment: will look in this for sure nuno , thanks for the help

Comment: I hope i could help you!! :)

Comment: @NunoBentes One thing i found is that i am displaying ( echo ) the paragraph from the database and making it truncate after 200 words see this  '.truncate($row[3], 200).'   using a function and there if it encounters a link it goes into the next div otherwise it works fine like in the first or second div.

Comment: Yes, but the problem you are having, it´s cause by the link that wraps the .col-md-4. Then all your code is fine!!!

Comment: maybe i am unable to explain the problem the whole code inside the div reviewbox is generated using PHP, so i have no control over it, the only thing i can do is store the text in the database which doesn't contain any links. actually i reallly dont want any links inside that revimg div

Comment: Ahhhh!! Okok, i understood. So yes, i identified the cause of the problem... so if you remove any link from the text, you won´t have this problem anymore, for sure!! :)